# C# Delete a specific XML node by attribute value, (xyz.parent.child.remove(xyz) is not an option

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li status="deleted">2</li>
<li>3</li>
<ul>
```

So i happen to have those kind of beauty XMLs and i have to delete all the nodes that has the STATUS attibute with a DELETED value.
The problem is that sometimes i come across "LI" and with those if you use xyz.parent.child.remove(xyz) u remove every li under the parent ul which is really bad.
Ohh i almost forgot theres like 40 different tags which can have this mighty status attribute (im using a control file where u specify the tags u want to clear).

What i tried:

```
foreach (var tag in controlTags)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(doc.Descendants(tag).Where(p => p.Attribute("status").Value == "deleted").Any())
                    {

                        doc.Descendants(tag).Where(p => p.Attribute("status").Value == "deleted").Remove();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
```

(gettin the possible tag names from a control file)

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (elemList[i].OuterXml.Contains("deleted"))
                    {
                        elemList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(elemList[i]);
                    }
```

this one was promising until i came across li tags :(

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<ul><li>1</li><li status=\"deleted\">2</li></ul>");
        var desc = doc.Descendants();
        for(int i = desc.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            XElement xe = doc.Descendants().ElementAt(i);
            if (xe.HasAttributes)
                foreach (XAttribute xa in xe.Attributes())
                    if (xa.Name == "status" && xa.Value == "deleted")
                    {

                        xe.Remove();
                        break;
                    }
        }
```

This results in an XDocument doc without the XElement with the "status = deleted" in it
*Note though* that you cannot use foreach since we have to traverse the list in opposite direction because we are removing elements. And we request the elemets from the origional source, not the cloned one.
The xe.Remove() method removes the current element from its parent, so we don't call the parent ourselves and we do not get conflicts with other, same-named, elements

Comment: Thank You! With doc.load() its working like a charm!
Cheers m8!